# Substituir trecho do codigo C#

Tags: c#, .net

Pessoal tenho uma duvida que acho que vocês vai saber solucionar.

Eu tenho um form de login de esta com a seguinte condição:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text == "1234" || textBox3.Text == "1234")
        {
            PDVForm form = new PDVForm(textBox1.Text);
            this.Hide();
            form.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
            form.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Usuário ou Senha Incorreta", "Erro",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
    }
```

porem vou ter que fazer com que ele altere o codigo do if:

```
        if (textBox2.Text == "1234" || textBox3.Text == "1234")
```

Na parte do 1234 que é o login e a senha inicial, porem se o usúario quiser mudar a parte do 1234 qual o codigo?

vou colocar no form de login para ele pegar o texto de outro form, e assim vai ter o novo login e a senha, porem não consigo fazer com que esse codigo altere o trecho 1234

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArg e)
{
   //Aqui vai o codigo de pegar o texto do campo textBox1
   //Aqui vai o codigo de pegar o texto do campo textBox2
   //Qual o codigo de mudar o 1234 para o texto digitado?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você quer fazer com que o login e senha sejam variáveis e deixam de ser literais, mas para isso, você precisa pegar essas variáveis de algum lugar. Se você quiser pegar de um outro Form, você terá que instanciar ele e então obter as propriedades dos campos.

Não faz sentido nenhum você ter um form para armazenar login e senha que será posteriormente utilizados em um form de login. Normalmente, login e senha são escritos em **bancos de dados**, **arquivos** ou **variáveis constantes**.

Além disso, a lógica do seu `if` está errada. Você deveria utilizar o operador **e** (`&`) ao invés de **ou então** (`||`), porque neste caso, se somente um dos campos estiver correto, já é entendido como login sucedido.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArg e)
{
    /*  
        Exemplo caso queira usar constantes
        Constantes não podem ter seus valores alterados.
    */
    const string loginUser = "1234";
    const string loginPass = "5678";

    /*
        Exemplo caso queira usar arquivos
        O texto das senhas requerem que os arquivos existam na mesma pasta do executável.
    */
    string loginUser = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("usuario.txt");
    string loginPass = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("senha.txt");

    if (textBox2.Text == loginUser && textBox3.Text == loginPass)
    {
        PDVForm form = new PDVForm(textBox1.Text);
        this.Hide();
        form.ShowDialog();
        this.Close(); // será chamado quando "form" for fechado
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Usuário ou Senha Incorreta", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima, você deverá utilizar somente um dos casos. Você pode implementar outros se quiser. Se mesmo assim quiser pegar as informações de um form, instancie ele e obtenha seus valores como você fez no `PDVForm form = new PDVForm();`.

Comment: Se resolveu seu problema, considere marcar essa resposta como correta, logo abaixo dos botões de voto.

Comment: Considere usar o operador `&&`, no lugar de `&`. Neste caso não é necessário avaliar a 2a parte caso a 1a já seja falsa. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-

Comment: @tvdias obrigado pela sugestão.